# How to convert DataTable to JSON using ConvertTo-json in Powershell v3

Tags: json, powershell

I have a DataTable $dt with same data, I would like to pipe the data to JSON using the cmdlet  **ConvertTo-JSON** in **Powershell** v3

```
$ds.Tables["mytable"] | ConvertTo-Json
```

The result is all the properties of the DataTable are returned, but I only need the records in the data table.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this without looking through each column/ row and adding then into a custom object..etc.

This is what I get when I run the above line;

```
[
    {
        "RowError":  "",
       "RowState":  2,
        "Table":  {
                  "CaseSensitive":  false,
                  "IsInitialized":  true,
                  "RemotingFormat":  0,
                  "ChildRelations":  "",
                  "Columns":  "Id Name IsActive",
                  "Constraints":  "",
                  "DataSet":  "System.Data.DataSet",
                  "DefaultView":  "System.Data.DataRowView System.Data.DataRowView",
                  "DisplayExpression":  "",
                  "ExtendedProperties":  "System.D.......
```

Thanks

Yasir

http://www.sqlist.co.uk

Comment: I've used following solution: http://mac-blog.org.ua/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-convertto-json/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After playing with a sample datatable a bit, I ended up with this:

```
($ds.Tables["mytable"] | select $ds.Tables["mytable"].Columns.ColumnName ) | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: perfect, just an extra )

Comment: oh ya this is very helpful.  I write my data to JSON files and it looks like this:

$JSONFileNameFormat = "C:\thao\nVision\Data\test\Json\{0}.{1}.JSON"

    $JsonOutputFile = [string]::Format($JSONFileNameFormat, $($Row[0]),$($Row[1]))

    ($DataSet_Table.Tables[0] | select $DataSet_Table.Tables[0].Columns.ColumnName ) | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File $JsonOutputFile

Comment: I found the essential transform here was: `$dt | select $dt.Columns.ColumnName`, that is enough to get an array of PS objects with the necessary properties.  From there you can iterate, or convert it all at once -- Great answer!

Answer (score 6):

You can also exclude properties with Select-Object, removing the noise.

```
$dt | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors | ConvertTo-Json
```